# JComboBox Not Showing Drop-Down Arrow After First Time Running

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have tried a lot to find help on google but i couldn't find anything related to my problem.I am facing a severe problem.I am using a JComboBox in my java program it showed only when I run the program first time but after that first time it's not showing drop-down arrow.I Haven't used any removeAll(); or any kind of remove(); methods.
Any help would be appreciated as I Have seen a lot people are suffering from the same problem.`class GPACalculator{
    JFrame frame;
    JLabel selection;
    JComboBox sub;
    Font f1;
    JTextField nameText;
    JButton enter;

```
public GPACalculator() {
    frame = new JFrame("GPA Calculator---COMSATS Institute of Information Technology");
    frame.setSize(720, 640);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    ImageIcon head = new ImageIcon("images/Header.jpg");
    JLabel header = new JLabel(head);
    header.setSize(720,90);
    header.setLocation(0, 0);

    ImageIcon log = new ImageIcon("images/Logo.png");
    JLabel logo = new JLabel(log);
    logo.setSize(300,300);
    logo.setLocation(480, 400);

    selection = new JLabel("Select Number Of Subjects And Press Enter");
    f1 = new Font("Gabriola",Font.BOLD,30);
    selection.setFont(f1);
    selection.setLocation(10, 150);
    selection.setSize(800, 50);

    String[] subject = {"1","2","3","4","5"};
    sub = new JComboBox<String>(subject);
    sub.setBounds(10, 200, 300, 50);

    Container c = frame.getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(null);
    c.setBackground(new Color(176,196,222));
    c.add(header,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    c.add(logo);
    c.add(selection);
    c.add(sub);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new GPACalculator();
}
```

}
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
c.setLayout(null);
```

Avoid using null layouts and instead use proper layout managers and your code will likely work well.

Comment: How to use proper Layout Mangers as i am new to java.

Comment: @ChaudaryUsman See this tutorial: [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot it was my first question to any online forum and this experience was awsome :-D

Comment: @LuxxMiner using FlowLayout() first worked but after running first time it's again the same problem.

Comment: @ChaudaryUsman Try calling `frame.setVisible(true);` **after** you added all components (i.e. just at the end of the constructor)

Comment: @LuxxMiner Thanks but what if i want to place my combobox and button at a specific place as after using flowlayout it put my button at the top

Comment: @ChaudaryUsman At what position do you want it to be? (Then I could suggest what layout manager to use). Also see [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/4857909) of nested layouts for some ideas.

Comment: @LuxxMiner Let me try I'll let you know if it didn't worked.
By the way thanks a lot for your help.